# Check if mp4 file is broken or corrupted flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web, flutter-test

How to check programmatically that an mp4 file is broken or corrupted in flutter? Is there a way to check if a file(any file format) is corrupted or broken in flutter? I need to check this before I upload it to firebase or any other database or even while loading the file in the app.

Comment: have you got the solution I am also looking for the same?

Comment: Nothing in particular, in my case I generated the mp4 in the app itself, so I could be a bit more lax. But I did come across a solution, you can use ffmpeg to decode the video and check for errors.For android, you could use mobile ffmpeg in order to do the decoding and testing part. Check out this link https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4